# Forward local ssh key to remote host

Tags: ansible, git, gitlab, ansible-playbook

I'm using ansible and i'm wondering. Is it possible to rewrite a local ssh key to a remote machine? I need to clone a repository using my private key on a remote machine. I cannot add the key from the machine in this case )this key will vary depending on who is starting the playbook)

I try:

```
~/.ssh/config
```

```
Host app01.dev.d
  User root
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dev
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p acd
```

The proxy is working fine.

~/.ssh/id_rsa.dev and ~/.ssh/id_rsa is added to gitlab in ssh keys

On remote machine:

```
ssh-add -l
```

```
The agent has no identities
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ssh-add -l`

Comment: @Ginnungagap, sure. Done.

Comment: You shouldn't copy your private key to other hosts. In this scenario, use a separate deploy key for git operations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's work:

On local machine:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dev
```